# Nexus 6P - cannot turn off Developer Options

Tags: nexus-6p, developer-options

On any other device, I was able to go to Settings, scroll to Developers Options and toggle it On/Off. On Nexus 6P, this toggle does nothing. If I turn it off, next time I look at it, it shows as on even though I turned it off minute ago.

I am building Android app so I do need Developer Options.  I dont want to disable or hide it, I just want to be able to use the toggle to turn it on or off as I need.  Just as I did with many other android devices.

Anyone else noticed this?

[image]

I tried suggestions from this link http://visihow.com/Disable_the_Developer_Options_on_Nexus_6P but that did not resolve anything.

I would also like to note that until very recently, perhaps 3 months ago, I was able to disable Developer Options by simply going to Settings->Developer Options -> Turn toggle Off

Comment: Seen [this](http://visihow.com/Disable_the_Developer_Options_on_Nexus_6P) ?

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, I saw it and did exactly as described.  This disabled developer options completely which is not what I wanted but anyways, upon enabling Dev Options again, the toggle was always on On.  Turning it Off, closing the settings, then reopening it again, shows it as On even though I set it to Off

Comment: In which case, [edit] your question to make it clear that you have tried the suggested steps but it didn't work. IMO, it looks like a specific issue with *your* device, since Google recommended method is linked by me below Antz's answer

Comment: Sorry, but question is very clear, but you are right, adding a line saying that I already tried suggestion from the link you posted helps, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory reset resolved this issue

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, have any idea why you downvote the only working solution for me? After trying numerous things including Google suggestions, they recommended this last resort thing.  Yes it is a sad solution, and to add, Nexus 6p is the worse phone I ever had

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this strange behaviour is caused by some setting that requires developer options to be enabled, but itself is not deactivated for instance USB debugging., transitions/animations etc.. (this has been observed to enable developer options in some LG builds typically when the battery saving feature disables animations at 15% )

As a workaround try this:

- Go to developer options, turn off debugging,
- Then disable the  developer options with the switch on top of the screen
  (same as your screenshot)

The trick is to first deactivate setting that uses developer options then toggle it off

Comment: Nope, not working.  As described already, and regardless whether I follow your 2 steps or not, behavior stays the same.  Toggling Developer Options to Off (in top right corner like on my image) shows it as Off.  But if I close Setting, then reopen it and go to Developer Options again, it will show it as On, even though I turned it Off just a minute ago

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, its not clear what you're trying to do. You say " I don't want to disable or hide it, I just want to be able to use the toggle to turn it on or off as I need" isn't toggling off disabling it? Also my point is some setting is causing the Developer options to be turned on, such that even if you disable it, you'll later find out it automatically turns itself on......as has been reported due to battery saving feature which turns off animations at a certain battery percentage in some LG builds, so either disabled it completely as suggested by @Antz or leave it

Comment: Well, there is a difference btw disabling Developer Options and turning it on/off.  Disabling it will remove Developer Option menu in Settings entirely.  To enable it again, you have to go to Setitngs->About Phone->Build Number, and tap 7 times on it to enable it again.  Doing so then adds Developer Options to Settings and you can go in there and toggle it on/off.   :).

Comment: Ok I understand, maybe its a bug of some sort? If I find something I will update accordingly ;)

Comment: I am starting to believe it is either device malfunctioning or a virus.  Having enabled Developers Options at all time is a huge security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **settings**, click **Apps**, then scroll down and select **settings**, click **storage**, you should have a pop-up window, click on **clear data**, then you finally click **ok**. It should bring you back to your home screen and **Developer Options** should go off until you decide to turn it on again.

Comment: Sorry but none of the answers so far make any sense.  I updated my question as well

Comment: This has been quoted as the way to do it in the [Google forums help](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18O_KLKLXeq1U/?hl=en) which had a linked video and a similar blog has been quoted by me below your question. I don't have the device to verify +1

Comment: @Antz This disabled developer options completely which is not what I wanted but anyways, upon enabling Dev Options again, the toggle was always on On.  Turning it Off, closing the settings, then reopening it again, shows it as On even though I set it to Off

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that no application is using the developer options. In my case, Fake GPS is using developer options, so I just had to disable it to turn off the developer options.

The trick is to disable the app or settings that are using the developer options.